# Double For Loop syntax in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, syntax

I am new to C and have to write some code that emulates a given function. However, I am having a difficult time understanding what the second for loop in this code is doing, explicitly. The syntax doesn't seem to follow standard for loop syntax of:

```
for ( init; condition; increment ) {
statement(s);
}
```

Here is the code I am examining and it's the second for loop that I am not following and I don't see any online version of this

```
for (i = 0; i <= (n1-n2); i++){   
    count=0;
    for(j = i,k = 0; k < n2; j++,k++){
        if (*(s1+j)!=*(s2+k)){
            break;
        }
        else
            count++;
        if(count==n2)    
            total++;                         
    }
}
```

I'm assuming it's two for loops in one, since there are two increments. And I think the inequality is similar to a 'while loop', but I'm not certain. The confusing piece is that there doesn't seem to be a condition for the j loop. I'm not sure if it's a syntax shortcut or if there is a special loop I can not find a resource for online.

Comment: `k < n2` is the condition for the inner loop - there is no requirement that it has to use the variable `j`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *I'm assuming it's two for loops in one, since there are two increments.*

Well, not really. The second `for` loop also follows the prescribed syntax, it's just a little fancy about handling the loop related variables.

For a loop statement like

```
 for(j = i,k = 0; k < n2; j++,k++){
```

can be interpreted as

```
 for( (j = i,k = 0)  ; (k < n2) ; (j++,k++) ){
       ^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^  
       init            condition    post loop body operation.
```

Now, the initialization and post-body expression blocks makes use of [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

Related, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.17

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a
>   sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand. Then the right
>   operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value.

To elaborate, the same syntax can be broken down to

```
 j = i;                               //initialization, only once
 for( k = 0  ; k < n2 ; k++ ){        // good ol' syntax
  //......loop body
  j++;                                //last expression in the body.
 }                                    //end of loop
```

Comment: Ok that is fantastic. So the j is 'along for the ride' sort of speak. And the k loop acts as a 'while' loop, it counts from 0 to 1 less than n2. is that an appropriate analogy?

Comment: @Joseph yes, almost, adding to that, `j` is also increased alongside `k` after every loop body execution.

Comment: So I ran the code and it appears the k loop resets on the k < n2 condition. The j loop continues counting until the 'break' condition is met in the if statement. Is that what should happen?

Comment: @Joseph what do you mean by the `k` loop and `j` loop?

Comment: I need to change my terminology, but, this is the output example:
    j is:  0  and k is:  0
    j is:  1  and k is:  1
    j is:  1  and k is:  0
    j is:  2  and k is:  0
    j is:  3  and k is:  0
    j is:  4  and k is:  0
    j is:  5  and k is:  1
    j is:  5  and k is:  0
    j is:  6  and k is:  0
    j is:  7  and k is:  0
    j is:  8  and k is:  0
    j is:  9  and k is:  0
    j is:  10  and k is:  0
    j is:  11  and k is:  0
    j is:  12  and k is:  1

Comment: @Joseph ahh.. I think I understood what you asked. If you're wondering that `j` value will be re-initialized to that of the value of `i`, then yes, it happens after the loop is -revisited. It's either due to the normal exhaustion of the loop condition, or de to `break`. The outer loop makes the control to enter the inner loop again and at that point, `j` gets that value of `i` and the inner loop starts all over again.

Comment: ok, so whats happening is that j is set to i and both j and k loop, and then the i loop advances, and both j and k loop ... until either i terminates or the break condition is met?

Comment: I need to get the right terminology - but i'm fairly certain I understand the syntax now. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can do multiple initialization and increment in a single `for` loop exactly as in your example (separated with a comma).

```
for(first = 0, second = 0 ; your_condition ; ++first, ++second)
    ...
```

This is useful when you need multiple variables to be updated each time in your `for` loop.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So the your_condition is the same ending condition for both loops?

Comment: @Joseph this is not a "two for loop in one", this is a single for loop with multiple variables. Thus, the for loop only needs one condition. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(j = i,k = 0; k < n2; j++,k++){
    initialisation  condition   increment or decrement
```

1. here they are considering two variables to keep track of.
2. Its not two for loops in a single `for loop`
3. the reason its done like that is to initialize and update variables each iteration.
4. Though you may have issues if you are using multiple type variables inside `for loop` for initialization